# Finding the impulse response given response to another signal

Tags: convolution, linear-systems, impulse-response, homework

I was trying to solve this question :
[image]

I respresented $x(t) = u(t+1)-u(t-1)$

writing the convolution as $[u(t+1)-u(t-1)]*h(t) = y(t)$

I then used the property of differentiation to convert from the step to the impulse function :

$[\delta(t+1) -\delta(t-1)]*h(t) = y'(t)$

$\implies h(t+1) - h(t-1) = y'(t)$

However , I am now stuck here. Moreover , the fact that the width of $y(t)$ is the same as that of $x(t)$ , bugs me a little.

How can I find the impulse response $h(t)$ using the given info ?

Comment: Could you also show the inputs $x_2(t)$ and $x_3(t)$?

Comment: @MattL. made the necessary edits

Comment: Are you familiar with Fourier transforms?

Comment: @cjferes: I'm afraid that this won't help much in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This exercise is meant to help the student appreciate the fact that if the response $y_1(t)$ of an LTI system to an input $x_1(t)$ is known, then the response to an input

$$x_2(t)=\sum_{k=1}^Ka_kx_1(t-t_k)\tag{1}$$

is given by

$$y_2(t)=\sum_{k=1}^Ka_ky_1(t-t_k)\tag{2}$$

which is a direct consequence of linearity and time-invariance.

Consequently, if an input signal can be expressed in the form given by $(1)$, it is not necessary to compute the system's impulse response in order to determine the output signal.

Also note that this exercise is almost a copy of problem P3.8 in [this MIT Signals and Systems problem set](https://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-6-007-signals-and-systems-spring-2011/assignments/MITRES_6_007S11_hw03.pdf). Only the input signals have been changed.

It now appears that the given signal $x_2(t)$ can't be expressed in the form $(1)$, whereas signal $x_3(t)$ can. I believe that this a mistake in the exercise, because as far as I can see, any other method to determine the solution is beyond what can be expected from a student at this level.

Comment: I am just not able to represent $x_2(t)$ as an linear combination through just time shifting and amplitude scaling . Seems as if time scaling would be required but that would change the response to $x_1(t)$

Comment: @Starboy: If that is the case then it's a mistake in the exercise. Check problem P3.8 of [these MIT signals and systems problems](https://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-6-007-signals-and-systems-spring-2011/assignments/MITRES_6_007S11_hw03.pdf). It's too close to be a coincidence.